# Encoding with UTF-8 creates wrong characters

Tags: html, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I wanted to insert a EURO sign into the HTML file and then I tried to safe it. Then an error message told me that the current Encoding wouldn't support that character, but I could apply UTF-8. After doing so several characters are displayed wrong.

Ã  is displayed instead of an X

What happened, why does it stay even if I change the encoding in the preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only changed the way the content of the file is interpreted. That's why any codepage-specific characters might be broken.

What you should have done is to convert the file contents to UTF-8 and **then** interpret it as UTF-8.